# Ошибки линковщика при подключении opencv

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2013

Здравствуйте всем,

Пытаюсь сделать программу, распознающую номера авто, получая изображение с IP камеры.
Делаю это с помощью iANPR, opencv.
Беру готовый пример программы по этой ссылке - http://recog.ru/blog/applied/202.html

Сделал вроде все, что нужно - в **"Linker -> Input ->Additional dependencies"** все библиотеки прописаны (т.к. проект скачан готовый, выложенный в качестве примера), в **"VC++ Directories"** прописаны **"Include Directories"** и **"Library Directories"**, все пути указаны верно.

При попытке сборки выводятся следующие ошибки:

```
Error   15  error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00063A) "public: void __thiscall cv::UMat::copySize(class cv::UMat const &)" (?copySize@UMat@cv@@$$FQAEXABV12@@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall cv::UMat::UMat(class cv::UMat const &)" (??0UMat@cv@@$$FQAE@ABV01@@Z)   D:\AutoWash3\IPtest2\camera.obj IPtest
Error   16  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall cv::UMat::copySize(class cv::UMat const &)" (?copySize@UMat@cv@@$$FQAEXABV12@@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall cv::UMat::UMat(class cv::UMat const &)" (??0UMat@cv@@$$FQAE@ABV01@@Z)    D:\AutoWash3\IPtest2\camera.obj IPtest
Error   17  error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals   D:\AutoWash3\IPtest2\Debug\IPtest.exe   1   1   IPtest
```

Погуглил, насколько я понял - подобные ошибки возникают, когда есть объявление функций, но нет их определения (может быть, не найден файл .dll). Не совсем понимаю, как lib и dll между собой связываются, просьба тапками сильно не кидаться.

Как это можно исправить, может кто-то сталкивался?

[image: VC++ Directories]